# using php to move a file

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, server

I am trying to upload a client file to my server (from an html form using a "post" method),  run a program on the $upldfile variable and then display the program results as downloadable links for the client.

My code is listed below and every time I run this I get the "file upload failed" notice.

Does anyone know if this is to with a permissions based problem or a server error or a code issue?

Thank you all in advance for any help offered

```
<?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);

        $destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $target_path = $destination_path . "uploads/" . basename( $_FILES["file"{["name"]);
        $upldfile = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path);

        if ($upldfile){
            echo "<p>File upload success.</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p>File upload failed.";
        }
```

Comment: If you do not use a target path the upload works?

Comment: `basename($_FILES["file"{["name"])` has a typo      `basename($_FILES["file"]["name"])`

Comment: is the uploads/ directory writable?

Comment: Has your form enctype='multipart/form-data' attribute?

Comment: Yes I have enctype in the form, thanks
I'm not sure where that is coming from Jordy, my script file is correct, though thank you
@RonaldSwets, How do I go about checking that? (that could be the problem)
MarcoMura, what do you mean by not using target path?

Thanks guys

Comment: If you are running a linux server, log in and check the permission by simply running something like "ls -al". If the uploads dir shows something like r--r--r--, the dir is not writeable. Assuming you run apache, you could: "chown apache:apache uploads/" and "chmod u+w,g+w uploads/", so the directory is apache owned and apache (group) writable.

Comment: managed to sort it out guys thanks, re the typo, no idea where it came from, I copied from my html file and it seemed to just appear in the code above while not in the original html.

Regarding the fix, yes the permissions was an issue though I had sorted that, since I am working with bioinformatics text files they are pretty big and so some settings had to be changed in the php.ini file to allow the upload of large files.  All good now, Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER:

Changing the permissions appropriately,

and also

modifying the php.ini file to allow larger file uploads.

The code itself in the original file was correct.